# I am using JFLA .In mealy I want to accept alphabet except letter 's' . in finite automat I can write [a-z[^s]] but this line is not working for melay

Tags: jflap

Jflap, mealy automata, Finite automata, TOC

I tried [a-z[^s]] in mealy machine , it works in Finite automata but not in mealy machine
I am using Jflap

Question : Check the string is containing your name using melay machine.

eg: Name is 'sam'

input : sam , output: 001
input : aaaasam , output: 0000001